# How solve integral with three moment and delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, feyncalc

I am trying solve this integral in mathematica:
\begin{equation}
\int \dfrac{d^3 p_3}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_3} \dfrac{d^3 p_4}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_4}(p_1 p_2)(p_3 p_4) \delta (p_3 + p_4 - p_1 - p_2).
\end{equation}
where $p_i$ ($i= 1, 2, 3, 4$) are the 3-momenta. I know already that the answer is:

$\int \dfrac{d^3 p_3}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_3} \dfrac{d^3 p_4}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_4}(p_1 p_2)(p_3 p_4) \delta (p_3 + p_4 - p_1 - p_2) = \dfrac{(p_1 p_2)^2}{8 \pi}$.

My doubt is: Is there any kind to solve the first integral in mathematica to obtain the second?

I was trying write the 3-momenta in spherical coordinates and put in mathematica. But the mathematica always give me the same integral that I write. In other words, the mathematica can not solve my integral.

Comment: What is $E_3$ and $E_4$?

Comment: Up to Encyclopedia of Mathematics (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function ), the integral under consideration makes no sense.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing 3 more deltas (or perhaps even more)? This looks like particle scattering, however those usually have $\delta^4$ which represents conservation of Energy($p_0$)-momentum($p_i$). As a matter of fact, I can't see how you can even get $E_3$ and $E_4$ to cancel out denominator terms. Particle physics has some conventions which often skip commonly repeated notation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Exchange network: physics.stackexchange.com